# Is calling std::fill() before std::erase() produces undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, stl, fill

I'm working on a C++11 program, where security is important and my task is to set to 0 the used memory after erasing it.

I have an `std::map` mapping from int to an `std::vector` of *pointer to class*. I have the index in `std::map` and a pointer to the instance I would like to delete.

The following code produces the output I want, however, I'm not sure if it's good formed code (or I would say I'm not sure if this code is ok or not).

I have 2 questions.

1. If the following code is ok,
2. It can only be compiled with `-fpermissive`, I don't understand the compiler error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


class MyClass
{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        MyClass(int num) { this->num = num; }
        int GetNum() const { return this->num; }
};


void PrintWorkingData(const std::map<int, std::vector<MyClass*>>& working_data, int idx)
{
    std::cout << "working_data[" << idx << "] is an std::vector, size: " << working_data[idx].size() << ", containing the following items: " << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<MyClass*>::const_iterator it = working_data[idx].begin(); it != working_data[idx].end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "(*it)->GetNum() = " << (*it)->GetNum() << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    MyClass* DeleteMyClass;

    std::map<int, std::vector<MyClass*>> working_data;
    working_data[0].push_back(new MyClass{4});
    working_data[0].push_back(new MyClass{7});
    working_data[1].push_back(new MyClass{11});

    // the origonal code isn't like this; let's suppose
    // we stored in the DeleteMyClass pointer the MyClass pointer
    // that we would like to delete
    working_data[1].push_back(DeleteMyClass = new MyClass{22});

    working_data[1].push_back(new MyClass{33});
    working_data[2].push_back(new MyClass{1000});

    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 0);
    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 1);
    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 2);
    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 3);

    // so our task is to delete DeleteMyClass object from working_data[DeleteItemIndex]
    // and fill with 0 where it was stored
    int DeleteItemIndex = 1;

    std::vector<MyClass*>::iterator pos = std::find(working_data[DeleteItemIndex].begin(), working_data[DeleteItemIndex].end(), DeleteMyClass);
    if (pos == working_data[DeleteItemIndex].end())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: The item does not present in the working_data" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::fill(pos, pos + 1, 0);
        working_data[DeleteItemIndex].erase(pos);
        delete DeleteMyClass;
        std::cout << "The object successfully deleted" << std::endl;
    }

    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 0);
    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 1);
    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 2);
    PrintWorkingData(working_data, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you've already removed the pointer from the vector then there's no need to set it to null since you won't be using it again.

Comment: It contains security information, and my task is to destroy the information. For example, please see http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SEC_admin/IS_HowObjReuseRelatesScur.html

Comment: You don't need `std::fill`, you can simply write `*pos = nullptr;` This is pointless though - `erase` call shifts subsequent elements to the left to fill the gap, so the element at `pos` will be overwritten anyway. It's the *last* element that will remain in the "garbage" portion of the vector, the memory between `size()` and `capacity()`.

Comment: Is your intent to clear out the memory occupied by the object that `DeleteMyClass` points to?

Comment: Note that the implementation is free to remove any (provably) dead stores; the language definition is concerned only with what your program can read (via defined behavior), not what’s physically in RAM.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: yes, exactly

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a pointer value to `nullptr` doesn't change the data it points to.  Erasing an element from a vector will overwrite that element with all the later ones in the vector, leaving (in this case) a second pointer in allocated memory (beyond the size of the vector) to the last element in the vector.

To erase the memory occupied by the object that `DeleteMyClass` points to, you'll have to handle the object destruction and memory freeing separately.  This is not necessarily easy or straightforward, as there can be nuances (exception handling, array vs. non-array forms) that need to be addressed.  You should also keep in mind that it is possible to inspect the memory of a running process, and view the data you're trying to erase while the object that uses it is live.

Here are several approaches that might work for you case.

One way to do this is to manually call the destructor, clear out the memory, then free it.

```
DeleteMyClass->~MyClass();
memset(DeleteMyClass, 0, sizeof(*DeleteMyClass));
delete (void *) DeleteMyClass;
```

The cast on the delete call is necessary to avoid calling the destructor, and the number of bytes to clear uses the type of `DeleteMyClass`, which will be incorrect if what is pointed to is a class derived from `MyClass`.

Another alternative is to use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) with an already allocated memory buffer and a custom deallocator (after manually calling the destructor) to free up the memory.

A third possibility is to use [custom `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) functions, either for this specific class or globally.